# Is there really no event based wysiwyg Gui builder for python/jython etc

Tags: python, wysiwyg

I am searching for month now and growing quite frustrated.

I just love python.

So after doing a lot of console based stuff I wanted to do some graphical UIs as well.

I am aware of most of the frameworks (wxpython, glade, tk etc).

But: I do **not** want to write the code for the GUI itself per hand! Declaring every element from hand, thinking about grids and doing a trail and error to find out just how many pixels you have to move an object to get it in the right place. Well, lets say that just sounds like 1990's to me, and it is no fun at all.

So to put it plain and simple, what I am looking for is a solution that allows me to design a GUI graphically (WYSIWYG) and have an event based linking to python code.

Almost all major languages have that: For C/C++ their are certainly the most IDEs/tools that can do that. For Java there is Netbeans with Wwing (example of what i want; it would be ideal if that UI designer in Netbeans could spit out jython code, but no: python is supported but not UIdesign). Even Mono/Visual Basic etc. has tools like that.

So why the hell is their nothing for python?

P.S. And please, no comments like "If you are are real programmer you do it by hand to get cleaner code". If I want something very specific I edit it by hand, but designing a standard UI by hand is a waste of time.

Comment: The question is worded in a hostile and combative manner. Please reword -- as it is, it fits the criteria for closing as "not constructive".

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what GUI Framework you want to use. The three most popular frameworks and popular graphical designers are:

1. [Qt Designer](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Developer-Tools/) — for [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/) or [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide)
2. [wxFormBuilder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/), [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/), [Boa Constructor](http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/) — for [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/)
3. [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) — for [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Well there is [pyQT](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)

You can check out [Qt Designer](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Creating_GUI_Applications_with_PyQt_and_Qt_Designer)

And just a comment to your request, no, not all `real` programmers write the GUI-code themselves, but try it out, it's quite educational and gives you a better sense of whats happening. It's not very common to use wysiwyg editors for html now is it? (that wasn't rhethorical)

Answer (score 0):

See [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/), particularly in use with the [libglade Python bindings](http://www.jamesh.id.au/software/libglade/).